# How to create a dynamic custom maps marker?

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, firebase-storage

How can I create a Google Map Marker that uses an image that is stored at a Firebase storage and a small view on the top right like a notification number which i can then manipulate when a message comes in?

[Desired Product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sip5W.png)

I'm so sorry; I'm using android studio, its and android app.

Comment: are you using angular?